# Re writing Funcition with APDU & Boolean

Tags: java, function, javacard, apdu, iso-7816-4

I need some help

I need that this function return a boolean if while is executed or no.

Could you help me?

Comment: Redraw? What does that even mean? Why do you need to redraw the method?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not very clear in my question , @Maarten Bodewes , I re-write my question

Comment: In the above code the while is always executed. Interesting, as I think this example comes [from the official API description of `APDU`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/APDU.html#setIncomingAndReceive()). Which means that should be rewritten. I might be able to do something about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us rewrite that APDU example from the API because it is clearly broken. It will generate a separate request to `receiveBytes` when it is not required.

```java
public boolean receiveIncomingFNEL(APDU apdu) {
    byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();

    short bytesRead = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    // NOTE: we must always call setIncomingAndReceive() first
    short offsetCdata = apdu.getOffsetCdata();
    short bytesLeft = apdu.getIncomingLength() - bytesRead;
    boolean receiveBytesRequired = true;
    while (true) {
        // --- do something with the bytes in buf, offsetCdata and bytesRead here
        if (bytesLeft <= 0) {
             receiveBytesRequired = false;
             break;
        }
        bytesRead = apdu.receiveBytes(offsetCdata);
        bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
    }
    // --- do other stuff
    return receiveBytesRequired;
}
```

The `if` & `break` statements in the `while()` loop are a bit weird, but that's the only way that I could think of to have one place handling the data in the APDU buffer and one part where `receiveBytes()` is called. This is because `setIncomingAndReceive()` includes a `receiveBytes()` within the call (ideas to create a normal `while` loop welcome).

Comment: Could you test drive this? I don't have a smartcard environment ready here.

Comment: Its working properly! Thanks a lot Maarten